# Including elements from unmodified lists in modified lists in a 2D list with Streams

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44210597/how-to-include-elements-from-unmodified-list-in-modified-list-with-java-streams) question about doing the same thing with 1D lists, figuring that it would be easy to apply the answers to 2D lists, but it was not.

Basing my code off of [Holger's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) answer, I came up with this solution:

```
//list is of type ArrayList<List<Integer>>
list.stream()
        .map(l -> Stream.concat(
                l.subList(0, l.size() - 1).stream().map(i -> i - 2),
                Stream.of(l.get(l.size() - 1)).collect(Collectors.toList())
        ))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I get the compile-time error `Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R>)`, however, when I try this.

How is can I perform this function on a 2D list?

Some example input and output:

`[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]` should output `[[-1, 0, 1, 4], [3, 4, 5, 8]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with the parenthesis. Change this:

```
list.stream()
    .map(l -> Stream.concat(
            l.subList(0, l.size() - 1).stream().map(i -> i - 2),
            Stream.of(l.get(l.size() - 1)).collect(Collectors.toList())
    ))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

To this:

```
list.stream()
    .map(l -> Stream.concat(
            l.subList(0, l.size() - 1).stream().map(i -> i - 2),
            Stream.of(l.get(l.size() - 1))).collect(Collectors.toList())
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Indentation is important here, to improve code readability. I would reindent the second snippet as follows:

```
list.stream()
    .map(l -> Stream.concat(
            l.subList(0, l.size() - 1).stream().map(i -> i - 2),
            Stream.of(l.get(l.size() - 1)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or even better, I would move the logic that modifies the inner lists to a helper method:

```
public final class Utility {
    private Utility() { }

    public static List<Integer> modifyAllButLast(List<Integer> list) {
        return Stream.concat(
                l.subList(0, l.size() - 1).stream().map(i -> i - 2),
                Stream.of(l.get(l.size() - 1)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

And then I would just use this method from the outer stream:

```
list.stream()
    .map(Utility::modifyAllButLast)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note: there's no need to move the helper method to a new `Utility` class and you might even let it be a non-static method. In this case, just change the `Utility::modifyAllButLast` method reference accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

### Let's fix the errors step by step

[Stream#concat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-) concats two streams together, but you concat one is a `List<Integer>`  not a `Stream<Integer>`.

```
list.stream().map(l -> Stream.concat(
    l.subList(0, l.size() - 1).stream().map(i -> i - 2),
    Stream.of(l.get(l.size() - 1)).collect(Collectors.toList())
   // it returns List<Integer> ---^
)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**THEN** we can fix the error by return a `Stream` as below:

```
list.stream().map(l -> Stream.concat(
    l.subList(0, l.size() - 1).stream().map(i -> i - 2),
    Stream.of(l.get(l.size() - 1))
)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**BUT** the result is not as expected. we expected it returns a `List<List<Integer>>` but it returns a `List<Stream<Integer>>` instead. we can collecting the concatinated streams to `List<Integer>` as below:

```
list.stream().map(main -> 
    Stream.concat(
        main.subList(0, main.size() - 1).stream().map(i -> i - 2),
        Stream.of(main.get(main.size() - 1))           
    ).collect(Collectors.toList())
//   ^--- collecting Stream<Integer> to List<Integer>
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**But** I think the best way in this case is using [List#replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) that I have answered in your [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44214154/7607923) which is more **expressiveness** and **faster** since `Stream` is more heavier than `Collector`.

```
list.stream().map(main ->
    main.stream().collect(collectingAndThen(toList(), it -> {
        // v--- replacing all items in list except the last one 
        it.subList(0, it.size() - 1).replaceAll(item -> item - 2);
        return it;
    }))
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most elegant way to concatenate the two lists, but it will do it.

```
list.stream()
    .map(integerList -> {
        List<Integer> toReturn = integerList
                .subList(0, integerList.size() - 1)
                .stream()
                .map(i -> i - 2)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        toReturn.add(integerList.get(integerList.size() - 1));
        return toReturn;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```